# Js check if window was minified or the screen was locked

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I have a small webpage(that will only run in mobile browsers) and i want to to check if the tab(or the entire browser) was minified or if the screen was locked.

I was looking at `Page Visibility API`:

```
function checkVisibility() {
    if (document.hidden) {
        //pause
    } else{
        //start
    }
}

document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', checkVisibility, false);
```

But i see that it only checks for `minified`(or the user is in another tab) and it doesn't make the distinction between `minified` and `screen lock`.

Is there a way to make this distinction using JS?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the lock-screen does not change the visibility state of a window or tab.
it would be required to write iOS and/or Android plugins, which make the status of the lock-screen available to JS  - eg. in case of using Cordova, Ionic or similar framework. when checking within a "common" web-browser, it's not possible to detect the lock-screen state, because it's not being exposed and one cannot expose it there, unless creating a web-browser extension/plugin with access to system APIs.

Comment: Hey @MartinZeitler, so in other words i have to write two apps just to check if the screen is locked? :(

Comment: @emma not two apps, but a single Cordova/Ionic plugin, which would support both platforms. obtaining & exposing a single value should not be too difficult, but there still may be some learning curve involved.

Comment: Dear @MartinZeitler, i have only two more little small questions: which one of those two(cordova/Ionic) would you recommend for me(a beginner)? and my laptop is runing windows and i have an iphone, is there any kind of app/environment in which i could run android on windows to to test my app?(i know it's offtopic buuuuuuuuuuuuuuut... :D)

Comment: @emma without OSX, it might not be possible to build for iOS (probably the reason why not too many developers consider it); there's just remote build for Cordova, as a workaround... for Windows, there's Android Studio (IntelliJ IDE) & Visual Studio Community Edition. just found this here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/first-steps/ios-guide?view=toolsforcordova-2017 ...which also builds remotely.

Comment: Oky :D still another question offtopic @MartinZeitler, i've installed Android Studio (and i checked that Android Virtual Device) but i don't see AVD in Tools tab :( What am i doing wrong? X_X

Comment: @emma there is a small icon in the top toolbar., called `AVD manager` ...